# Cassanda Performance

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am looking to increase the performance of my 4 node Cassandra cluster.  The insert performance of the cluster is great but the read performance is only around 400/s with latency of about 300ms-500ms.  These are mainly all random reads by primary key.  The nodes all have 40GB Ram, 1 SSD and 1 WD SE drive.

The table that is having the issue has 800mil keys and the hit rate is .08.  Bloomfilters are set to 0.01 and read_repair to 0.1  It seems to be an IO issue but the RAM is not being utilized to even 20%.

Should I increase the key_cache_size?  heap size? add another drive? Any suggestions would be appreciate.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the current value of your max_heap?  If you haven't set it, casssandra-env.sh should compute it at 1/4 RAM with a max of 8GB.

Comment: what is your schema definition for the table?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously 300-500 ms latency is bad for just about any application. What are your latency requirements? If your latency requirements are strict, I'm not sure you are going to be able to tune away the overhead that a database written in Java is going to bring.

Take a look at this [case study](http://aerospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Aerospike-AppNexus-SSD-Case-Study_Final.pdf) where AppNexus performs over 200K transactions per second per node with sub-millisecond latency using [Aerospike](http://www.aerospike.com/).